# Can you set a name for your Gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Or can you by giving a nickname to the Pokemon that is guarding the gym? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Gym names are based on the location of the gym, and your Pokemon nicknames are not visible to other players.

Answer (score 2):

No, the name of the Gym is not changeable, just like names of Poké-Stops.